# Android: How to retain my intent open on screen change

Tags: android, android-intent, android-orientation

From my main activity I open an intent with textboxes to edit data, but on screen rotation the opened intent closes and leaves only the starting activity. How should I handle it so that my secondary intent is not closed on screen rotation.

Comment: Post your code on how you start the second activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` in your activity declaration in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

or handle you data in

```
 @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // store the data in bundle
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

and restore the data in

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // restore the data from bundle and settext to edittext
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: I have those, but still my secondary activity closes and continues with my main activity.

Comment: I had made a minor mistake in my code and what you wrote helped me see it. Thanks.